Adding a prefix or suffix to the names of POJOs generated with jooq maven plugin
I have the maven plugin set up so it generates jooq classes including POJOs from a Postgres database. My config looks like this:
<generator>
    <generate>
        <pojos>true</pojos>
        <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
    </generate>
    <database>
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
    </database>
    <target>
        <packageName>xxx.yyy</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
    </target>
</generator>

I'm happy with all the generated code, except I would like to add a prefix of suffix to the class name of the POJOs, e.g. Db... - it should be the same for all the POJOs.
I found some information how to do it programmatically, but so for I just have the maven plugin. I understand it's probably related to what's documented here https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generator/ but I can't figure it out.

Use a generator strategy, either:

A programmatic one
A configurative one (see also table specific configuration)

In the latter case, it could be as simple as:
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <strategy>
      <matchers>
        <tables>
          <table>
            <expression>.*</expression>
            <pojoClass>
              <transform>PASCAL</transform>
              <expression>PREFIX_$0_SUFFIX</expression>
            </pojoClass>
          </table>
        </tables>
      </matchers>
    </strategy>
  </generator>
</configuration>


Interestingly, this adds the suffix twice. So e.g. if I use $0_SUFFIX, for my "product" table a "ProductSuffixSuffix" pojo class is generated.

It works fine if I remove the .* :) Thank you!
